# What is a "grav" and why does it require email?

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, profile-page

When you edit your profile, each field includes some help text to explain what it is for. The text for Email gets cut off (Chrome 10.0.648.205):

[image]

What on Earth could this mean? The obvious choice is *gravity*, but I don't see how email could relate. So I have to go with my second choice: *grave digging*.

So please expand the Email field so it can include the entire phrase "never displayed, optional notifications, grave digging".

Comment: I always assumed it meant "graviton blasters".

Comment: Well now I'm incredibly disappointed with the lack of grave digging emails I've received as a result of registering here.

Comment: @Daniel - they haven't finished digging your grave yet.

Comment: Just in case: it's indicating the email address is used for gravatar.com: *"never displayed, optional notifications, gravatar"*

Comment: +1 for the [undertaking] tag. -1 for making poor meta people believe you actually don't know what the "grav" means. +1 for freehand circle. Net weight: +1.

Comment: Mmm, gravy. Delicious, delicious bacon gravy. So rich and tasty. ...what were we talking about, again?

Comment: You should [learn your units](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/grav)!

Comment: Just so we're all clear: @Popular Demand wins.

Comment: @status-declined, I'm all out of invites for the PGP 2.0 beta (that's Portable Gravy Protocol) at the moment, but you're first on my list for when I get more!

Comment: maybe if you'll change your display name to `status-completed` this will be fixed! :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build with a bit more verbose description and a new `390px` width to fit it:

[image: updated email field]

Comment: Oh, and I had been hoping for gravy. Oh well.

Answer (score 3):

It's for your [gravatar](http://www.gravatar.com/), which is the purple picture in your profile. It's there for people (like you) who haven't uploaded a profile picture.

Comment: He actually had one for a couple of years. The real bug report is that the fields are too narrow. I guess.

Comment: @mmyers - new bug report: meta users have lost their sense of humor :(

Comment: @status: See, if TheTXI hadn't left, we'd now have six different answers giving possible interpretations.

Comment: @mmyers I miss the old days. I even miss Evan.

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

[image]

```
$("input[name=Email]").prev().andSelf().css({width:300})
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if your using chrome go to the http://www.threetipsaday.com/2008/12/debug-inspect-google-chrome-inspector/ inspect element. If you ever want to see truncated text online.

Also very useful to see starred comments on chat.meta.stackoverflow.com whatever that may be.

Answer (score 0):

It is clear enough, they are sending you a congratulation message,  although some shorthand used.

```
Email never displayed optional notifications gravid
```

means

```
Email never sent, displayed your optional notifications because you are gravid
```

Translated into the lame jargon comprehensible by technical people, you could get (clarifications commented for the real hardcore tech guys out there)

```
Dear Sir/Madam, 
     It is our pleasure to write this letter /*not an email*/ to inform
     /*aka notify*/ you that the results of our latest linq query indicates 
     you are mostly gravid /*aka pregnant*/. HTH!
```

See? easy!